# Parameter tuning in classification

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, hyperparameter, threshold

Recently, I am digging into the selection of tuning parameters in a binary classification.

I gathered information by googling and the following is my organization.

1. We can distinct binary classification problems into two cases

- Balanced classification: the proportion of the two classes is about 5:5
- Imbalanced classification: the proportion of the two classes are not balanced

2. In imbalanced classification problems, "accuracy" is not a good metric for model performance

- Almost classification algorithms are developed considering the balanced classification, thus, if our data set is imbalanced the algorithm classifies almost observations as the dominate class.
- Therefore, although we cannot correctly classify the fewer proportion class, the accuracy is very high

3. Hence, when we tune our tuning parameters by using cross-validation, the accuracy is not a good metric

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there any wrong part in my knowledge?
2. If my thought is not critically wrong, I think, we can use the accuracy to tune the parameters in the "balanced" classification problems. But, I am not sure whether that is correct idea
3. In every classification, we have to choose a probability threshold (= decision threshold (cutoff) = discriminant threshold (cutoff)). Considering the discussion above, it is not a good idea to use "accuracy" to select the threshold as a metric only in the imbalanced classification problems. I think, however, accuracy could be a good metric in the threshold selection in a balanced classification problem. Is this idea non-problematic?

Thank you for your time to read this long question.

Comment: Someone not on their phone—this is a good time to link to Frank Harrell’s remarks on proper scoring rules, and on where the statistical part of the exercise ends. Otherwise, I can do this tomorrow.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I have my favorite links saved on my phone! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en